# Cake PHP show videos ORDER BY rating

Tags: php, sorting, pagination, cakephp

Now I began to get acquainted with the Cake PHP.

The following is the problem:
I have two tables. The two models look like this:

```
class Video extends AppModel {
var $ name = 'Video';
var $ hasMany = array ('Rating' =>
array ('className' => 'Rating',
'foreignKey' => 'model_id'
'Conditions' => array ('Rating.model' => 'Video');
'dependent' => true,
'exclusive' => true
)
);
}


class Rating extends Model {
var $ name = 'Rating';

var $ validate = array ('user_id' => array ('rule' => array ('MaxLength', 36),
'required' => true);
'model_id' => array ('rule' => array ('MaxLength', 36),
'required' => true);
'model' => array ('rule' => 'alphanumeric',
'required' => true));
}
```

It looks like a query that works is:

```
$ this-> paginate = array (
'Video' => array (
'limit' => 15,
'page' => 1,
'order' => array (
'Video.id' => 'DESC')
)
);
$ this-> set ('videos', $ this-> paginate ("Video"));
```

I would like to sort by rating

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` char(36) NOT NULL default '',
  `model_id` char(36) NOT NULL default '',
  `model` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `rating` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(100) default '',
  `created` datetime default NULL,
  `modified` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `rating` (`model_id`,`model`,`rating`,`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=61 ;
```

Thank you in advance for answers.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should have an average rating field in your Video table. This will improve performance and make it really easy to do what you're asking for above.

After a user adds a new rating. Use the following formula to re-calculate the field:

```
new_avg_rating = (old_avg_rating + rating) / rating_count;
```

Similarly if a user removes a rating:

```
new_avg_rating = (old_avg_rating - rating / rating_count;
```

"rating" is the rating being added or deleted, rating_count is the number of records in the "rating" table for that video. Since you do this after adding/deleting the new rating to the table it already includes the new one.